# Adding a value when clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, button, click

I want to add `10` to `0` every time I click a `button` and show it on the screen. I've tried everything but I can't get it to work.

This belongs to a longer code:

```
var bet = 0;
pen.fillText('Bet: ' + bet, 350, 390);

function reactToBetIncrease() {
    bet += 10;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would include the portion of code where you actually call the function `reactToBetIncrease()`. The calling context will matter a lot in your case. Is the `bet` variable a global (part of the `window` object)?

Comment: perhaps you need to display the new value as well? You don't seem to do that.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm new to this, sorry. My actual code is longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var bet=0;

pen.fillText('Bet: '+bet,350,390);

function reactToBetIncrease()

{

    bet += 10;
    pen.fillText('Bet: '+bet,350,390);
}
```

Comment: Another question. When I click the button the numbers overlap, how do I remove the old one?

Comment: `pen.font = '20pt Calibri';
pen.fillText('Inzet: '+inzet,350,390);`

Comment: this is very simple in generic, it's done like this: element.value+=10;

Comment: `var pen=c.getContext("2d");`

Comment: oh you are using canvas, that's another question, I don't know much about canvas

Comment: I think you should clean canvas and redraw text, but don't know how

Comment: Ok, I'll try something. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button id="myButton">
```

JavaScript

```
var bet = 0;
$("#myButton").click(function() { bet += 10; });
```

**Note:** I don't know what your `pen` object is, nor what library it's from. It may require a single call on update - in which case it should live in the *click callback*. Otherwise it may require a call each frame. Since you haven't specified exactly what it does, I've left this out.

Comment: note that this alone won't affect the display in any way. It's still useful if attaching the handler was a problem.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I have no idea what `pen` is. And the question seemed like the handler was the problem, that's why I answered it.

Comment: And yet if it was polling the variable (bad idea) then most likely it wouldn't be passed a string generated from the variable.